Does adding count to a module/resource change the resource?
I have a bunch of modules. I want to change them all from
module "foo" {
  # whatever
}

to
module "foo" {
  count = 1 # because I want to make creating the module conditional, and this is the only way to do it
  # whatever
}

terraform plan tells me it's going to tear down all the resources these modules create and create new ones, presumably because a resource with a count of 1 is not the same as a resource that doesn't have a count, right? Is there a way to avoid this?

You could execute many terraform state mv, but it would probably be better to re-design your root config such that you do not declare a module conditionally.

The desire is to allow a local developer to provision only the module/resources they are working on, while in the cloud all resources will be provisioned. I don't know of a way to do this non-conditionally.

Unfortunately, using for_each or count in modules always changes the resource addresses in Terraform, which will lead to recreation of resources (unless you all terraform state mv them).
Assuming you are using your own modules here and no 3rd party modules, you can resolve it by adding a condition in each of the resources within the module.
i.e.
module "foo" {
  create_module_foo = false
  # whatever
}

In (all of) the resources within the module, add a condition like:
   resource "foo1" "default" {
     for_each = var.create_module_foo ? {for foo1 in var.foo1 : foo1.name => foo1 } : {}
     # whatever

This will not change the resource addresses
